# R's data.table can not find the function "."

Tags: r, data.table

I read that data.table understands the dot "." as an alias of "list".
But:

```
> dt <- data.table(x = c(11, 22), y = c("f", "b"))
> dt
    x y
1: 11 f
2: 22 b
> dt[,.(y)]
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "."
>
```

Why is that?

Comment: Which version of data.table you have ? This works in devel version though.

Comment: @akrun I am using 1.9.2

Comment: This may be introduced recently.  You could try with `1.9.4` or the devel  `1.9.5`

Comment: Check this link https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation

Comment: Yes, you are right, it works in 1.9.4. Are you going to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the data.table New features on `v.1.9.4` (https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table),

> .() can now be used in j and is identical to list(), for consistency with i.

So, it is better to install either `v.1.9.4` version or the devel version from [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)